# Flag as "a duplicate" vs "should be closed -> duplicate of"

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I recently noticed that there are two very similar flags that can be used, "a duplicate" and "should be closed -> duplicate of".

[image]

[image]

They look like they should accomplish the exact same task, and I don't see the point of having both of them. Why do both of these flagging options exist and do they do the same thing?

Comment: Related?: [The new Hierarchical Flag Menu has issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196682)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There is no difference

The two buttons are just duplicates (pun intended) of each other.

The action that comes from doing [*Flag > Duplicate*], or [*Close > Duplicate*], or [*Flag > Close > Duplicate*] is exactly the same.

Comment: Do you know why they both exist?

Comment: Probably just because "why not". Voting to close and raising a flag are two different things, as to how they are handled internally, but they are very similar from the point of view of the user who flags/votes. A user might just find easier, when they find that something is wrong with a question, to just click "flag" and compare the options