Why are there three ways to reach the dupe menu?
There are three different ways to flag/vote to close a question as a duplicate in the UI:

Flag -> A duplicate
Flag -> Needs improvement -> Duplicate
Close -> Duplicate

Admittedly, the last option is slightly different from the first two. However, having three routes for very similar features is unintuitive.
Why is this so?

I'm not your downvoter, so I can only comment about the prospects of my own voting.  The first impression is that your post is overly terse; it doesn't seem to reflect research on the history of these mechanisms.  However you might be a newish user, and the second thought I have is that your observation is novel.  I'd never thought about the apparent redundancy.  In general I have enough rep to vote-to-close without bothering with flagging (that would be my typical for spam/rudeness rather than duplication).  So I give you credit for looking at things from a different POV.

If a user mightv reasonably expect to find the duplicate menu in three separate places, what's the harm of putting it in all of those places?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321129/356669

Seeing how many people still answer blatant duplicates, perhaps three locations for dupe closure still isn’t enough…

"However, having three routes for very similar features is unintuitive." uh, it's the exact opposite. It offers more routes, therefore, different people can use what is most intuitive to them. I don't get why you believe this to be a problem.

Also, you say "very similar features" - do you believe these aren't the same?

I've also removed the [[tag:duplicate-answers]] tag as I see how it applies. Do feel free to add it back with an explanation for how duplicate answers are relevant for the flag/close reason that is only for questions.

The question has merit, but answer can be given same way in the other questions asking the same thing. My best guess is that it's combo of historical behavior and redundancy on purpose, e.g. like there are several links to the help center. (top bar help icon, top bar site list then help, etc.)
